# Retrieving data using ajax from a webmethod ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json

I know my question is very basic but somehow my code is not working.
I am trying to update a label value on textbox text change. Below is the sample of the javascript code which I am writing on my aspx page.

```
function UpdateDescription(ControlID) {//debugger;
    ControlID = "ctl00_CP_" + ControlID;
    UPCCode = document.getElementById(ControlID).value;
    //alert(UPCCode);
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",                    
        url:"ProductPhotoRequisitions.aspx/GetUPCJSon",
        //data: "{UPC:" + UPCCode + "}",
        data: "UPC=" + UPCCode,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {alert(data.d);} 
    }); 
}
```

I am writing the webmethod in codebehind of the same page but somehow this function is not being called.

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetUPCJSon(String UPC) 
{ 
    //code to fetch label value
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code for the GetUPCJSon web method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your javascript is ok and if your only problem is the method not being called you should try and use this, the method should be static

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string GetUPCJSon(String UPC) 
 { 
    //code to fetch label value
 }
```

Comment: Also check this tutorials [link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

WebMethod must be declared as static, and they must be decorated with the [WebMethod] attribute.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetUPCJSon(String UPC) 
{ 
   //code to fetch label value
}
```

since content type json send parameters as jsonobject

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",                    
        url:"ProductPhotoRequisitions.aspx/GetUPCJSon",
        data: "{UPC:'" + UPCCode + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {alert(data.d);} 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Static was one issue but the main issue was single quotes were not provided for parameters. It should have been

```
 $.ajax({ type: "POST",                    
        url:"ProductPhotoRequisitions.aspx/GetUPCJSon",
        data: "{'UPC':'" + UPCCode + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {alert(data.d);} 
    });
```